# How to rotate an object around another rotating object in CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have these two rotating objects and I want the `.box` to be rotating around the `.circle` like the ring and the earth but I can't seem to figure out how to do it,
I would also like to distribute the images around the space (like the image posted instead of the alphabets it the `.box` images) if possible I would really appreciate it.

Thanks in advance!
[image: This image]

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    min-height: 100vh;
    background-color: #000;
}
.circle {
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform: perspective(1000px) rotateY(360deg) rotateX(15deg);
    /* animation: animate 8s linear infinite; */
}
.circle span {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: #fff;
    color: blueviolet;
    font-size: 3em;
    transform-origin: center;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    padding: 5px 11px;
    border-top: 4px solid blueviolet;
    border-bottom: 4px solid blueviolet;
    transform: rotateY(calc(var(--i) * calc(360deg/30))) translateZ(250px);
}
.box {
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform: perspective(1000px) rotateY(3600deg);
    /* animation: animate 200s linear infinite; */
}
@keyframes animate {
    0% {
        transform: perspective(1000px) rotateY(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        transform: perspective(1000px) rotateY(3600deg);
    }
}
.box span {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    transform-origin: center;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform: rotateY(calc(var(--i) * 45deg)) translateZ(400px);
}
.box span img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/try.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="box">
        <span style="--i:1"><img src="assets/try.png"></span>
        <span style="--i:2"><img src="assets/try.png"></span>
        <span style="--i:3"><img src="assets/try.png"></span>
        <span style="--i:4"><img src="assets/try.png"></span>
        <span style="--i:5"><img src="assets/try.png"></span>
        <span style="--i:6"><img src="assets/try.png"></span>
        <span style="--i:7"><img src="assets/try.png"></span>
        <span style="--i:8"><img src="assets/try.png"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="circle">
        <span style="--i:1;">a</span>
        <span style="--i:2;">a</span>
        <span style="--i:3;">a</span>
        <span style="--i:4;">a</span>
        <span style="--i:5;">a</span>
        <span style="--i:6;">a</span>
        <span style="--i:7;">a</span>
        <span style="--i:8;">a</span>
        <span style="--i:9;">a</span>
        <span style="--i:10;">a</span>
        <span style="--i:11;">a</span>
        <span style="--i:12;">a</span>
        <span style="--i:13;">a</span>
        <span style="--i:14;">a</span>
        <span style="--i:15;">a</span>
        <span style="--i:16;">a</span>
        <span style="--i:17;">a</span>
        <span style="--i:18;">a</span>
        <span style="--i:19;">a</span>
        <span style="--i:20;">a</span>
        <span style="--i:21;">a</span>
        <span style="--i:22;">a</span>
        <span style="--i:23;">a</span>
        <span style="--i:24;">a</span>
        <span style="--i:25;">a</span>
        <span style="--i:26;">a</span>
        <span style="--i:27;">a</span>
        <span style="--i:28;">a</span>
        <span style="--i:29;">a</span>
        <span style="--i:30;">a</span>
    </div>
    <script>
        let circle = document.querySelector('.circle');
        let box = document.querySelector('.box');

        window.onmousemove = function (e) {
            let x = e.clientX;
            let y = e.clientX;

            circle.style.transform = `perspective(1000px) rotateY(${x * 0.5}deg) rotateX(15deg)`;
            box.style.transform = `perspective(1000px) rotateY(${y}deg)`; // Adjust rotation speed
        };
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you describe what specifically you would like to change from the code you have already shared? As it stands it's difficult to understand the specific requirement.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand (There's no codepen or anything), but I suspect you'll need to have a different `perspective` on the boxes and the circle. (And maybe a `z-index` too.)

Comment: @EliezerBerlin
I want the circle with a to be rotating inside the pictures that are also rotating, like the a finder and a ring for example i want the circle to be like the finger and the pictures like a ring to rotate around the finger

Comment: @deepanshu223
I want the circle with a to be rotating inside the pictures that are also rotating, like the a finder and a ring for example i want the circle to be like the finger and the pictures like a ring to rotate around the finger

Comment: The limitation comes from the fact that `transform-style: preserve-3d;` creates a different a 3D environment for both your containers. And z-index won't have an effect on it. You should probably look at a library like [ThreeJS](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#manual/en/introduction/Creating-a-scene) in order to achieve that.

Comment: If my solution was useful, Consider accepting it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use scale3d() css function and acheive the same output.

```js
      let circle = document.querySelector(".circle");
      let box = document.querySelector(".box");

      window.onmousemove = function (e) {
        let x = e.clientX;
        let y = e.clientX;

        circle.style.transform = `perspective(1000px) rotateY(${
          x * 0.5
        }deg) rotateX(15deg)`;
        box.style.transform = `perspective(1000px) rotateY(${y}deg)`; // Adjust rotation speed
      };
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-color: #000;
}
.circle {
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform: perspective(1000px) rotateY(360deg) rotateX(15deg);
  /* animation: animate 60s linear infinite; */
}
.circle span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: #fff;
  color: blueviolet;
  font-size: 3em;
  transform-origin: center;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  padding: 5px 11px;
  border-top: 4px solid blueviolet;
  border-bottom: 4px solid blueviolet;
  transform: rotateY(calc(var(--i) * calc(360deg / 30))) translateZ(250px);
}
.box {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform: perspective(1000px) rotateY(3600deg) scale3d(2.5, 2.5, 2.5);
  animation: animate2 200s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes animate {
  0% {
    transform: perspective(1000px) rotateY(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: perspective(1000px) rotateY(3600deg);
  }
}
@keyframes animate2 {
  0% {
    transform: perspective(1000px) rotateY(0deg) scale3d(2.5, 2.5, 2.5);
  }
  100% {
    transform: perspective(1000px) rotateY(3600deg) scale3d(2.5, 2.5, 2.5);
  }
}
.box span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transform-origin: center;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform: rotateY(calc(var(--i) * 45deg)) translateZ(400px);
}
.box span img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/try.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="box">
      <span style="--i: 1"><img src="https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/2626/2626299.png" /></span>
      <span style="--i: 2"><img src="https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/2626/2626299.png" /></span>
      <span style="--i: 3"><img src="https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/2626/2626299.png" /></span>
      <span style="--i: 4"><img src="https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/2626/2626299.png" /></span>
      <span style="--i: 5"><img src="https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/2626/2626299.png" /></span>
      <span style="--i: 6"><img src="https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/2626/2626299.png" /></span>
      <span style="--i: 7"><img src="https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/2626/2626299.png" /></span>
      <span style="--i: 8"><img src="https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/2626/2626299.png" /></span>
    </div>
    <div class="circle">
      <span style="--i: 1">a</span>
      <span style="--i: 2">a</span>
      <span style="--i: 3">a</span>
      <span style="--i: 4">a</span>
      <span style="--i: 5">a</span>
      <span style="--i: 6">a</span>
      <span style="--i: 7">a</span>
      <span style="--i: 8">a</span>
      <span style="--i: 9">a</span>
      <span style="--i: 10">a</span>
      <span style="--i: 11">a</span>
      <span style="--i: 12">a</span>
      <span style="--i: 13">a</span>
      <span style="--i: 14">a</span>
      <span style="--i: 15">a</span>
      <span style="--i: 16">a</span>
      <span style="--i: 17">a</span>
      <span style="--i: 18">a</span>
      <span style="--i: 19">a</span>
      <span style="--i: 20">a</span>
      <span style="--i: 21">a</span>
      <span style="--i: 22">a</span>
      <span style="--i: 23">a</span>
      <span style="--i: 24">a</span>
      <span style="--i: 25">a</span>
      <span style="--i: 26">a</span>
      <span style="--i: 27">a</span>
      <span style="--i: 28">a</span>
      <span style="--i: 29">a</span>
      <span style="--i: 30">a</span>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```